# How to scale SVG in R/Exams

Tags: r-exams

I am struggling to scale an SVG file with R Exams using RStudio on Windows. I would appreciate any help. Here is the SVG file I am using:

https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/atom.svg

Here is a complete code:

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
include_supplement("atom.svg", recursive = TRUE)
@

\begin{question}
What is 2 + 1?

\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{atom.svg}

\begin{answerlist}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{001}
\exshuffle{3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the `scale=0.1` attribute is not supported by `converter = "ttm"` (the default for .Rnw exercises) nor by `converter = "pandoc"` or `"pandoc-mathjax"`. However, the latter supports the `width=` attribute. So both of the following work correctly with pandoc:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{atom.svg}
```

or

```
\includegraphics[width=4in]{atom.svg}
```

For example, with the latter we get:

```
exams2html("atom.Rnw", converter = "pandoc")
```

[image: Screenshot of the atom.Rnw exercise as rendered by exams2html with pandoc converter.]

Comment: I really appreciate your quick and great solution!